# Can't execute python script via system() call in PHP

Tags: php, python-3.x, linux, permissions, webserver

I am developing module for web server. In one of my php modules I am using `system($command, $response)` call in order to execute python script, but I get response "1" which means *"operation not permitted"*. I did the following actions in order to solve this problem, but nothing helped:

1. `chmod 777` for every php file in execution pipeline and `chmod 777` for executed *my_python_script.py*.
2. `chown my_server_daemon` for *my_python_script.py*.

A little more useful information for case understanding:

- Server system: Linux 2.6.32-042stab141.3 x86_64 GNU/Linux
- Python file was written on Win10, but line ending were changed using `dos2unix my_python_script.py`

Do you have any ideas how to solve this problem? Everything works fine, when I execute script manually in terminal, but fails, when I try to do this using PHP system().

Answer (score 0):

The question is closed. It's really stupid, I didn't pay attention that *my_python_script.py* works with external .txt file, which hadn't write permission for other users. Be careful :)